# Getting count of strings in vector c++

Tags: c++, string, stl, vector, count

I have this vector

```
vector <string> data

data = ["this is", "data that", "is in", "this is", "vector", "vector", "vector"]
```

how do I get a vector (or 2D array) that removes duplicates and instead has the counts       for each ith entry?

i.e.

```
 results = [("this is", 2), ("data that", 1), ("is in", 1), ("vector", 3)]
```

Comment: Xeo, I've tried a LOT of approaches. i.e. for each string s in data, look at the rest of the elements in data, and increment count for each match of s. looks like this is O(n^2) but I'm looking for something a bit more efficient

Comment: You might want to try a `std::map<string, int>`... you can index by the string, and increase the counter as needed.  `map`s are sorted by key (here string), and can't have duplicates.  To take an unsorted list/vector of strings and populate a map is an O(N x log2N) operation.

Comment: This sounds like a collision (hash) table to me. Try looking it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The straightforward solution would be to accumulate the unique values and their counts into a map:

```
std::map<std::string, std::size_t> results;
std::for_each(begin(data), end(data), [&](std::string const& s)
{
    ++results[s];
});
```

This has linearithmic (n lg n) time complexity, though because it must make a copy of each distinct string value, it may be rather expensive.  You could also sort the list in-place, then count the number of each value, which would likely perform better if you have a move-aware implementation of `std::string`.

Comment: You could also just use a `std::reference_wrapper<std::string>` as the key.

Comment: how about a Hash Table? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table (complexity O(n))

Comment: @MihaiTodor: Just change `std::map` to `std::unordered_map`

Comment: @MihaiTodor:  `unordered_map` may not perform better, and in the worst case it may perform far, far worse.  Self-balancing binary search trees have far more predictable performance characteristics, which is often desirable.  Unless you know for sure that an unordered container will improve performance, I'd recommend sticking with the ordered containers (though, there's certainly nothing wrong with trying out the unordered containers to see if they will help).

Comment: I think that really depends on the particular details of the data, and in this case, my guess is that he should just try the simplest method first. He might get lucky and even choose the best solution this way. Always keep stuff simple when you're a beginner :)